# AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'items' - Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying selenium on Opera browser and I keep getting this error.
I have tried using the `service` kwarg but I just keep getting `TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'`

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(r'path\to\operadriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Opera(service)
```

Comment: did you try `driver = webdriver.Opera(options=service)` ?

Comment: it just gave me `AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see here from the documentation of the WebDriver API (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.opera.webdriver):

```
__init__(executable_path=None, port=0, options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, opera_options=None, keep_alive=True)
Creates a new instance of the operadriver.

Starts the service and then creates new instance of operadriver.

Args:   
executable_path - path to the executable. If the default is used
it assumes the executable is in the $PATH
port - port you would like the service to run, if left as 0,
a free port will be found.
options: this takes an instance of OperaOptions
service_args - List of args to pass to the driver service
desired_capabilities: Dictionary object with non-browser specific
service_log_path - Where to log information from the driver.
opera_options - Deprecated argument for options capabilities only, such as “proxy” or “loggingPref”.
```

The webdriver.Opera doesn't have a service object parameter.

Instead you can check this example here:

```
    from selenium import webdriver

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.binary_location ="<your opera executable directory>"
    driver = webdriver.Opera(options=options)
    driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
    # make sure 'operadriver.exe' is in the same folder as your directory
```

Comment: This fixed it for the most part, but now I'm getting `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Failed to create Opera process.`